# Why my Fragment gets always only default value from jetPack dataStore, even if it (the value) has been changed already?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-datastore

Why everytime I open the Fragment the switchButton is always in the position of the default nativeToForeign value (always the value that assignet as default to the nativToForeign variable in dataStore) (with respective text), although when I click switchButton, in dataStore log I see that changes were made successfully?

DataStore:

```
   @Singleton
class PreferencesManager @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext context: Context) {

    private val dataStore = context.createDataStore("user_preferences")

    val categoryNumberFlow = dataStore.data
        .catch { exception ->
            if (exception is IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error reading preferences", exception)
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            } else {
                throw exception
            }
        }
        .map { preferences ->
            val categoryChosen = preferences[PreferencesKeys.CATEGORY_CHOSEN] ?: 
            categoryChosen
        }

    val translationDirectionFlow = dataStore.data
        .catch { exception ->
            if (exception is IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error reading preferences", exception)
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            } else {
                throw exception
            }
        }
        .map { preferences ->
            val nativToForeign = preferences[PreferencesKeys.NATIV_TO_FOREIGN] ?: false //always this value, if 
            //if I change it to true - switchButton is always turned ON (with respective String value of text)
            Log.d(TAG, "So, trans nativeTOForeign: " + nativToForeign)
            nativToForeign
        }

    suspend fun updateCategoryChosen(categoryChosen: Int) {
        dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[PreferencesKeys.CATEGORY_CHOSEN] = categoryChosen
            Log.d(TAG, "updateCategoryChosen: $categoryChosen")
        }
    }

    suspend fun updateTranslationDirection(nativToForeign: Boolean) {
        dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[PreferencesKeys.NATIV_TO_FOREIGN]
            Log.d(TAG, "updateTranslationDirection: $nativToForeign")
        }
    }

    private object PreferencesKeys {
        val CATEGORY_CHOSEN = preferencesKey<Int>("category_chosen")
        val NATIV_TO_FOREIGN = preferencesKey<Boolean>("nativ_to_foreign")
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
class SettingsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.settings_layout) {

    private val viewModel: SettingsViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var binding: SettingsLayoutBinding

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        /*val */binding = SettingsLayoutBinding.bind(view)

        binding.apply {
            viewModel.readTransDir.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated:  transDirPreference = $it")
                switchTranslationDirection.isChecked = it
                switchTranslationDirection.text =
                    if (it) "Native to swedish" else "Swedish to native"
            }
        }

        binding.switchTranslationDirection.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, boolean ->
            viewModel.saveTransDir(boolean)
        }

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class SettingsViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val preferencesManager: PreferencesManager
    ) : ViewModel() {

    private val transDirFlow = preferencesManager.translationDirectionFlow

    val readTransDir = transDirFlow.asLiveData()

    fun saveTransDir(nativToForeign: Boolean) = viewModelScope.launch {
        preferencesManager.updateTranslationDirection(nativToForeign)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot “= nativeToForeign” in updateTranslationDirection